# How to launch root-needing scripts using a systemd service?

Tags: linux, bash, systemd

I am attempting to start a couple of things on startup in CentOS, but I'm encountering some issues I don't know how to solve.

Here is my.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description="Boot Jenkins slave and SonarQube server"
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/var/boot.sh
User=root
Group=root

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

After `systemctl daemon-reload`, `systemctl enable my.service` and `systemctl start my.service`, nothing actually seem to happen/work.

The output of `systemctl status my.service` is:

```
$ systemctl status my.service 
● startup.service - "Boot Jenkins slave and SonarQube server"
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/my.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2017-04-26 19:49:31 IDT; 1min 41s ago
  Process: 988 ExecStart=/var/boot.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 988 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Apr 26 19:49:00 build-1 systemd[1]: Started "Boot Jenkins slave and SonarQube server".
Apr 26 19:49:00 build-1 systemd[1]: Starting "Boot Jenkins slave and SonarQube server"...
Apr 26 19:49:00 build-1 boot.sh[988]: Starting SonarQube...
Apr 26 19:49:01 build-1 boot.sh[988]: Started SonarQube.
```

Supposedly, things should have worked, but they don't...
However, if I will manually run boot.sh, they do work.

```
su ...
./boot.sh
```

boot.sh is:

```
#!/bin/bash

nohup java -jar /var/jenkins/slave.jar -jnlpUrl https://***.jnlp -secret **** &
/var/sonarqube-6.3/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start
```

Note that SonarQube requires root.
What am I doing wrong?

**Update:** logs from `cat /var/log/messages | grep SonarQube`:

```
Apr 26 20:58:53 build-1 systemd: Started "Boot Jenkis slave and SonarQube server".
Apr 26 20:58:53 build-1 systemd: Starting "Boot Jenkis slave and SonarQube server"...
Apr 26 20:58:53 build-1 boot.sh: Starting SonarQube...
Apr 26 20:58:53 build-1 boot.sh: Started SonarQube.
```

Comment: Try checking the logs with `journalctl -xe`, it should tell you what is happening...

Comment: Unfortunately no error is logged there, or anything related to the above.

Comment: Then maybe try doing `cat /var/log/messages | grep SonarQube`. The `inactive` status might not be what you think it is; services can become `inactive` until they are needed, so it's actually loaded and enabled.

Comment: But not actually started, as the server is still offline. See updated question (bottom) for the log.

Comment: When the script is run via systemd, it never finishes IMO, and when it is run manually, it does (as I do `su` and then run it).

Comment: Thanks Mark. I also flagged the question as requested to move it. I hope that if it gets closed, it'll at least be open once moved...

Comment: You're not seeing any errors relating to `jenkins` because you're using `nohup`, which sends output to a `nohup.out`. Drop the `nohup` in your `boot.sh` and it will become more informative. Also, you don't need an external script for this, you can use multiple `ExecStart=` sections: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStart= `Commands may be specified by providing multiple command lines in the same directive, or alternatively, this directive may be specified more than once with the same effect.`

Comment: Thanks. I've removed `nohup` and pasted the command as-is to `ExecStart`. Still doesn't work... and still not logs. sigh.

Answer (score 0):

For SonarQube I ended up just following this instead: https://devopscube.com/setup-and-configure-sonarqube-on-linux/, which instructs how to add SonarQube as a service... that was oddly quite simpler than the systemd approach.

For the first command in the file, that's still an open issue...

Comment: SonarQube is still being managed by systemd, but now it's happening through a sysVinit compatibility layer.